# Different values in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to understand the cosinor analysis in Matlab.
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20329-cosinor-analysis/content/html/cosinor.html

I'm not understanding the find() function, actually this line: IND = find(real(beta_s1) ~= real(beta_s2));

Can someone tell me why Matlab considers these values equal?

4.4115 + 2.0221i

4.4115 - 2.0221i

Thanks

Comment: The code line checks only the real part. So they're roughly the same. But probably they are [not exactly the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab/686454#686454). Depending on application, it is usually very bad practice to compare floating-point numbers exactly.

Comment: Ok, I understood, thanks a lot.